# Backbone View receiving regular object instead of model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Here I am passing a model to a Backbone view.

```
 view = new View ({model:{item:4,name:"Ipad"}});
```

When I console.log that model from within the View. I get:

```
Object {item: 4, title: "Ipad"}
```

This is not a backbone model therefore I don't have methods
like toJSON. I realize that if I define a Backbone model and 
passed it in everything works fine.

```
view = new GenreView ({model:new Model({title: 4, title: "Ipad"})});
```

This logs

```
 r {cid: "c2", attributes: Object, _changing: false, _previousAttributes: Object, changed: Object…}
```

Why is it that first approach doesn't work and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its simply that the special 'model' option expects a Backbone.Model not a javascript object.

So you are correct when you create a new Backbone.Model to pass into the view.

There is nothing to fix as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `Backbone.Model` instead of a regular JavaScript object `{}`

```
var Item = Backbone.Model.extend({
  // ...
});
```

Instantiate the `Item` model

```
var myItem = new Item();
```

Now use your item in the view

```
var myView = new View({model: myItem});
```

---

This answer assumes that `View` is setup as something like

```
var View = Backbone.View.extends({
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could cast the object to a Backbone Model in your view's `initialize` method:

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(options){
    if (_.isPlainObject(this.model)) {
      this.model = new Backbone.Model(this.model);
    }
  }
});
```

This way the view will be able to operate on it's `model` regardless of whether you passed it an instance of a `Backbone.Model` or a plain object. You can see an example of it working here: http://jsbin.com/igecEgE/1/edit?js,console